# PHP-SQL: Column count error, but only value not inserted is ai primary key

Tags: php, sql, primary-key, column-count

I have a recipe table with 20 fields, and through a form, I've filled up 19. But am getting an insert failed error - 'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1'. The only column I haven't filled in is the auto increment primary key value (which I'm guessing should be taking care of itself), so I'm not sure why this error is happening. Would appreciate any help.

Here is the php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php
  require_once 'login_news.php'; 
  include ('newscss.php');
  $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
  if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);


if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['uniqno']))
  {
    $uniqno   = get_post($conn, 'uniqno');
    $query  = "DELETE FROM recipes WHERE uniqno='$uniqno'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) echo "DELETE failed: $query<br>" .
      $conn->error . "<br><br>";
  }


//var_dump($_FILES['imagine']);
if (isset($_POST['btn'])){
    $recregion  = get_post($conn, 'recregion');
    $recpostdate     = get_post($conn, 'recdate'); 
    $recpostdate     = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($recpostdate));
    $rectitle   = get_post($conn, 'rectitle');
    $recsummary   = get_post($conn, 'recsummary');
    $reccontributor   = get_post($conn, 'reccontributor');
    $ingredcontent     = get_post($conn, 'ingredcontent');
    $prepsubhead1   = get_post($conn, 'prepsubhead1');
    $prepcontent1 = get_post($conn, 'prepcontent1');
    $prepsubhead2     = get_post($conn, 'prepsubhead2');
    $prepcontent2   = get_post($conn, 'prepcontent2');
    $prepsubhead3     = get_post($conn, 'prepsubhead3');
    $prepcontent3   = get_post($conn, 'prepcontent3');  
    $prepsubhead4     = get_post($conn, 'prepsubhead4');
    $prepcontent4   = get_post($conn, 'prepcontent4');  
    $prepsubhead5     = get_post($conn, 'prepsubhead5');
    $prepcontent5   = get_post($conn, 'prepcontent5');      

     if($_FILES['imagine']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE){
            $filetmp = $_FILES["imagine"]["tmp_name"];
                $recpicname = $_FILES["imagine"]["name"];
                $recpictype = $_FILES["imagine"]["type"];
                $recpicpath = "images/".$recpicname;

                move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $recpicpath);          

        $query    = "INSERT INTO recipes VALUES" .
          "('$recregion', '$recpostdate', '$rectitle', '$recsummary', '$reccontributor', '$recpicname', '$recpicpath', '$recpictype', 
          '$ingredcontent', '$prepsubhead1', '$prepcontent1', '$prepsubhead2', '$prepcontent2', '$prepsubhead3', 
          '$prepcontent3', '$prepsubhead4', '$prepcontent4', '$prepsubhead5', '$prepcontent5')";
        $result   = $conn->query($query);

        if (!$result) echo "INSERT failed: $query<br>" .
          $conn->error . "<br><br>";
     }
     else{

        $query    = "INSERT INTO recipes VALUES" .
          "('$recregion', '$recpostdate', '$rectitle', '$recsummary', '$reccontributor', '$ingredcontent', 
          '$prepsubhead1', '$prepcontent1', '$prepsubhead2', '$prepcontent2', '$prepsubhead3', 
          '$prepcontent3', '$prepsubhead4', '$prepcontent4', '$prepsubhead5', '$prepcontent5')";
        $result   = $conn->query($query);

        if (!$result) echo "INSERT failed: $query<br>" .
          $conn->error . "<br><br>";

     }   
  }

?>
 <form action="recipes.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><pre>
            Recipe's Region <input type="text" name="recregion">
            Date of Posting <input type="text" name="recdate">
                RecipeTitle <input type="text" name="rectitle">
                Summary <textarea rows="5" cols="60" name="recsummary"></textarea>
            Contributor <input type="text" name="reccontributor">  
         Ingredient Content <textarea rows="15" cols="60" name="ingredcontent"></textarea>
       Preparation Subhead1 <input type="text" name="prepsubhead1">
       Preparation Content1 <textarea rows="15" cols="60" name="prepcontent1"></textarea>
       Preparation Subhead2 <input type="text" name="prepsubhead2">
       Preparation Content2 <textarea rows="15" cols="60" name="prepcontent2"></textarea>
       Preparation Subhead3 <input type="text" name="prepsubhead3">
       Preparation Content3 <textarea rows="15" cols="60" name="prepcontent3"></textarea>    
       Preparation Subhead4 <input type="text" name="prepsubhead4">
       Preparation Content4 <textarea rows="15" cols="60" name="prepcontent4"></textarea>     
       Preparation Subhead5 <input type="text" name="prepsubhead5">
       Preparation Content5 <textarea rows="15" cols="60" name="prepcontent5"></textarea>

            <input type="file" name="imagine">
           <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Upload Image & ADD RECIPE RECORD">          
  </pre></form>



<?php


  function get_post($conn, $var)
  {
    return $conn->real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
  }

  ?>
  </html>
```

**Here is the full error message:**

> INSERT failed: INSERT INTO recipes VALUES('Assam', '2000-12-12
>   00:00:00', 'Wingnuts', 'The best way to eat your heart out', 'Walia',
>   'firstfood.jpg', 'images/firstfood.jpg', 'image/jpeg',
>   'Water\r\npaper\r\nnuts\r\nbarberries\r\nbamboo shoots', 'Wash', 'Wash
>   thoroughly\r\nPat dry', 'Dry Fry', 'Heat on Skillet\r\nAdd
>   spices\r\nLet cool', 'Add water', 'Put in rain water\r\nMix around',
>   'Salt', 'Add himalayan sea salt', 'Sing', 'Hold up platter\r\nSing
>   well') Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

And here is the table structure:
[image]

Comment: Learn about prepared Statement. it makes your query readable and prevent you agains SQL injection.

Comment: The error is clear. You should mention the column names while inserting except the primary key. Only 19 values are there.

Comment: Oops - yes. & looking into prepared statements

Comment: @Sougata - would mark yours as the answer but dont think its possible to do so on a acomment

Answer (score 0):

Your table has 20 columns, but you only add 18 values to your insert query. 
You have to add the volumn names  or add null values to the column you will not fill with values.

```
insert into recipes (<column names>) values(<values>)
```

For more Information about the insert into syntax look at the official [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

Comment: Try the following example without column names:

insert into recipes values(NULL,<your 19 other values>);

Answer (score 0):

uniqno column missing in your query that's why it throw error Column count doesn't match.
replace

```
 $query    = "INSERT INTO recipes VALUES" .
      "('$recregion', '$recpostdate', '$rectitle', '$recsummary', '$reccontributor', '$ingredcontent', 
      '$prepsubhead1', '$prepcontent1', '$prepsubhead2', '$prepcontent2', '$prepsubhead3', 
      '$prepcontent3', '$prepsubhead4', '$prepcontent4', '$prepsubhead5', '$prepcontent5')";
```

with

```
 $query    = "INSERT INTO recipes VALUES" .
      "('','$recregion', '$recpostdate', '$rectitle', '$recsummary', '$reccontributor', '$ingredcontent', 
      '$prepsubhead1', '$prepcontent1', '$prepsubhead2', '$prepcontent2', '$prepsubhead3', 
      '$prepcontent3', '$prepsubhead4', '$prepcontent4', '$prepsubhead5', '$prepcontent5')";
```

Comment: Please share the why part too. This is just a group of characters without any useful information. Please share how or why your code will work, what did you change and why.

Comment: `uniqno` column missing  in your query that's why it throw error  Column count doesn't match

Comment: I know :) Always answer to a visitor, who will read this page a week or month later. The OP will know what is the problem (probably), you know what is the problem, the girl/guy who will read this answer later will not. You can quote the documentation (and link it ofc), just make it clear, why is this an answer, how it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - this has been resolved by a comment on the question @Sougata - however couldn't mark it as the answer as it is in the comment. As many have since pointed out, the issue was - I had left out specifying which columns the values applied to, in the INSERT query. Eventually used this:

```
$query    = "INSERT INTO recipes (recregion, recpostdate, rectitle, recsummary, reccontributor, recpicname, recpicpath, recpictype, 
  ingredcontent, prepsubhead1, prepcontent1, prepsubhead2, prepcontent2, prepsubhead3, 
  prepcontent3, prepsubhead4, prepcontent4, prepsubhead5, prepcontent5) VALUES" .
  "('$recregion', '$recpostdate', '$rectitle', '$recsummary', '$reccontributor', '$recpicname', '$recpicpath', '$recpictype', 
  '$ingredcontent', '$prepsubhead1', '$prepcontent1', '$prepsubhead2', '$prepcontent2', '$prepsubhead3', 
  '$prepcontent3', '$prepsubhead4', '$prepcontent4', '$prepsubhead5', '$prepcontent5')";
$result   = $conn->query($query);
```